# MongoDb $near query in using java not giving proper locations

Tags: java, mongodb, geolocation, geospatial, mongodb-query

I have query regarding `$near` in mongodb

I have to find out the users from particular location around the radius.

I have location `[ 18.58528075595879 , 73.73364686965942]` , and from which i want to search the users from `250` yards radius.

I have users table in which I have `gpsloc` array.
I have put index "2d" on gpsloc

```
db.users.ensureIndex({loc: "2d"})
```

The query which i am trying

```
{ "gpsloc" : { "$near" : [ 18.58528075595879 , 73.73364686965942] , "$maxDistance" : 228.6} , "height" : "Average" , "hair" : "Brown" , "gender" : "Male"}
```

What it takes in `maxDistance (distance in meters/km/?)`

Answer (score 0):

> *What it takes in maxDistance (distance in meters/km/?)*

As per the [docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/near/#definition):

> To specify a point using legacy coordinates, $near requires a 2d index
>   and has the following syntax:

```
{$near:[ <x>, <y> ],$maxDistance:<distance in radians>}
```

The parameter should be fed with a value in `radians`.

For a `2dsphere` index, the parameter takes in the input in `meters`.

Comment: but how to convert 250 meters to radians, I want to track the users in 250 yards . please help.

Comment: by putting 2dsphere index i am getting following error :"$err" : "can't parse query (2dsphere): { $near: [ 18.5874338, 73.7380072 ], $maxDistance: 240.0 }",